# Есть ли замена bot.register_next_step_handler

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Пишу ТГ бота в telebot.
Такой вопрос. bot.register_next_step_handler(send,function) - перейдет в функцию только после какого-то ввода от пользователя. Есть ли какая то альтернатива, чтобы оно делало это само. Типа: bot.change_function(function). И он окажется в функции function на вход который подан message ?

```
def a(message):
    schedule.every(3).seconds.do(function(message)).tag(str(message.chat.id))
def funtction(message):
    ....
```

Пытаюсь подать так, но жалуется.
TypeError: the first argument must be callable

Comment: А в чем различие?

Comment: Потому что вызвав bot.register_next_step_handler вас не переведет в другую функцию, пока вы не напишите что-то в бота. А мне нужна функция, которая перекинет без написания

Comment: просто передать  управление функций

Comment: Конкретнее можно?

Comment: Хоть для приличия в документацию по schedule заглянули. https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html#pass-arguments-to-a-job в вашем случае
 `schedule.every(3).seconds.do(function, message=message)).tag(str(message.chat.id))`